# gradient accumulation stopping at 50%

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient

[image: training stopping at 50%]

the original batch_size = 16, but I wanted to give accumulation = 2 so that I have a similar effect as when I used batch_size = 32.

The original training time lasted an hour, so I expected 2 hour training time with the gradient accumulation.

But the training ends at 50%, lasting an hour even with the gradient accumulation.

I don't know why it's stopping.. below is my code for training

def train_runner(model, train_dataset, valid_dataset , batch_size, num_train_epochs, learning_rate):
device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')

```
model.to(device)
model.train()
train_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)
valid_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset = valid_dataset, batch_size = batch_size)

lowest_total_valid_loss = 9999.
step = 0
global_total_step = len(train_dataloader) * num_train_epochs
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, weight_decay=0)
print("TRAIN START")
with tqdm(total=global_total_step, unit='step') as t:
    total = 0
    total_loss = 0
    for epoch in range(num_train_epochs):
        for iteration,batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
            #optimizer.zero_grad()
            input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device)
            attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
            start_positions = batch['start_positions'].to(device)
            end_positions = batch['end_positions'].to(device)
            outputs = model(input_ids,
                         attention_mask=attention_mask,
                         start_positions=start_positions,
                         end_positions=end_positions)
            loss = outputs.loss
            (loss / ACCUMULATION).backward()

            step += 1
            if step % ACCUMULATION:
                continue

            clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=1.)
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad(set_to_none=True)
            
            batch_loss = loss.item() * len(input_ids)
            total += len(input_ids)
            total_loss += batch_loss / ACCUMULATION
            global_total_step += 1
            t.set_postfix(loss="{:.6f}".format(total_loss / total), batch_loss="{:.6f}".format(batch_loss))
            t.update(1)
            
            del input_ids
            del attention_mask
            del start_positions
            del end_positions
            del outputs
            del loss

            ## validation ##
            if iteration != 0 and iteration % int(len(train_dataloader) / 10) == 0:
                total_valid_loss = 0
                for batch_val in valid_dataloader:
                    model.eval()
                    optimizer.zero_grad()

                    input_ids = batch_val['input_ids'].to(device)
                    attention_mask = batch_val['attention_mask'].to(device)
                    start_positions = batch_val['start_positions'].to(device)
                    end_positions = batch_val['end_positions'].to(device)
            
                    with torch.no_grad():
                        outputs = model(input_ids,
                                attention_mask=attention_mask,
                                start_positions=start_positions,
                                end_positions=end_positions)
                        loss = outputs.loss
                        total_valid_loss += loss.item()
                
                if total_valid_loss < lowest_total_valid_loss:
                    print(f"lowest_total_valid_loss: {total_valid_loss} epoch : {epoch} iteration : {iteration}")
                    torch.save(model.state_dict(),'./output_model_best')
                    lowest_total_valid_loss = total_valid_loss
            ## validation ##

#model.save_pretrained("./klue_output_model")
print("TRAIN END")
```

Comment: Please add your image as part of your question rather than as a link. Also, it may be helpful to add more tags to your question to give better context

Answer (score 0):

```py
for iteration,batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):    
    if step % ACCUMULATION:
       t.update(1) # add one update here as well.
       continue 
    ...
    t.update(1)
```

Half of the time you do not update the tqdm counter or set its value too high during initialization. So it can't go higher than 50%.

Comment: Thanks..! Then should I put t.update(1) above the if conditions?

Comment: I've learned that if u apply accumulation=2, the time for training gets doubled, but the time isn't changing at all.. do u think the gradient accumulation is working in this case?